# AttributeError: module 'keras.engine' has no attribute 'input_layer'

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to use google colab!

But I keep running into the problem with keras where it says:
AttributeError: module 'keras.engine' has no attribute 'input_layer'

However, checking their github library, there is a input_layer.py within keras/engine.

Also, this works locally, just not on google colab.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)) / What do you expect? / What error do you get? **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: There is not enough information to answer the question, the problem itself is not clear. Please add code or steps that reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The above import works on your local device because you are not using any hardware accelerator (GPU) on your local device. I do not know the reason as to why this import does not work on GPU runtimes. Here are two workarounds for this.

1. Change the Colab runtime to **None** and this import will work fine.
2. I looked at the code of *input_layer* and found that it has a **Input** (function) and **InputLayer** (class). So, If you do not want to change the runtime, you need to refactor things.

Remove

```
from keras.engine import input_layer.InputLayer
from keras.engine import input_layer.Input
```

to

```
from keras.layers import InputLayer, Input
```

I wish both do the same thing

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem with google colab. The error I am getting is:

module 'tensorflow._api.v1.keras' has no attribute 'engine'.

Here is my code:

```
 import tensorflow as tf
 from tensorflow import keras
 from keras import backend as K

 def reinitLayers(model):
     session = K.get_session()
     for layer in model.layers: 
         if isinstance(layer,keras.engine.network.Network):
             reinitLayers(layer)
....
```

However there exist keras.engine:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/python/keras/engine