# Google colab does not find keras.engine when reinitializing a neural net weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, google-colaboratory

I need to create a simple model of Neural net with small number of nodes, to train it and then to evaluate certain parameters in the resulting already trained network.

I need to repeat this several times(>100). Thus, I just want to reinitialize the weights instead of creating a new model every single time.

Here is the problematic part of my code:

```
 import tensorflow as tf
 from tensorflow import keras
 from keras import backend as K

 def reinitLayers(model):
     session = K.get_session()
     for layer in model.layers: 
         if isinstance(layer,keras.engine.network.Network):
             reinitLayers(layer)
....
```

This is what I am getting:

```
 "module 'tensorflow._api.v1.keras' has no attribute 'engine'"
```

However there exist keras.engine:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/python/keras/engine

Very similar question is this one:
[AttributeError: module 'keras.engine' has no attribute 'input_layer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186448/attributeerror-module-keras-engine-has-no-attribute-input-layer/55250831#55250831)
However, the answer there doesn't help me.

The same issue is described here, but the thread there does not help either:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/341

Answer (score 0):

Could you not reshuffle the weights and use them instead of reinitializing as mentioned in https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/341? What is the problem with that?

### Update

I ran the following code

```
def reinitLayers(model):
    session = K.get_session()
    for layer in model.layers: 
        if isinstance(layer, keras.engine.network.Network):
            reinitLayers(layer)
            continue
        print("LAYER::", layer.name)
        for v in layer.__dict__:
            v_arg = getattr(layer,v)
            if hasattr(v_arg,'initializer'):
                initializer_method = getattr(v_arg, 'initializer')
                initializer_method.run(session=session)
                print('reinitializing layer {}.{}'.format(layer.name, v))
```

(given at https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/341#issuecomment-423637768) on google colab. It worked both with and without GPU, and I was able to reinitialize the network. In other words, I could not reproduce your error. Double check that you used this code, and try running it again.

Comment: i want to repeat the same experiment multiple times. Reshuffling might bias the results

Comment: I am getting the same mistake with PyCharm on my PC

Answer (score 0):

Restarting colab and run again worked for me

Comment: Please post your this type of answer in comment section if it contains code then its okay to post in answer section so please be make sure in future