# Why is there no documentation for keras.engine?

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to use https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN, but get the error
`AttributeError: module 'keras.engine' has no attribute 'Layer'`.

I'm not the only one who's had this problem - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67905185/module-keras-engine-has-no-attribute-layer?noredirect=1&lq=1) are some suggestions for how to solve it.

Now, trying to better understand the problem, I have searched for documentation of the `keras.engine` module, but have found nothing. In [the official Keras API reference](https://keras.io/api/), there seems to be no mentioning of anything called 'engine'. Why is this the case? How is one supposed to use a module for which there is no documentation?

Comment: Its not documented as it is not part of the public API, you should not use it, it was a mistake for matterport so use that module instead of the public API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TLDR

No one** is supposed to use the `keras.engine` module because it is not part of the [public API](https://lwn.net/Articles/795019/).

## Explanation

In most projects (e.g. Keras) the assumption is that you shouldn't rely on features that are not documented because they can change at any time. I think that's exactly what happened here. As Dr. Snooppy pointed out in the comments, Matterport shouldn't have called `keras.engine.Layer` for precisely this reason.

## Finding docs and source

Keras is open source and `keras.engine` is full of docstrings, so if you really want to get to the source of something it's not that hard:

- Find the `site-packages` folder with `python -m site`
- Navigate to `.../site-packages/tensorflow/keras/python/engine`
- Check out the source files. Pay particular attention to the `class` keywords and to class and method [docstrings](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/docstrings) (These are delimited by `"""`).
- In my Tensorflow/Keras version 2.6.0, a file search yields that `class Layer` is now in a different place than the two mentioned in the linked answer:  `.../site-packages/tensorflow/keras/python/engine/base_layer.py`, illustrating the point that anything that's not part of the public API may and does change all the time.

** Obvious exception: the engineers who write code for the Keras library.